# Max degree of vertex related to line graph of regular bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to figure out a relationship between the max degree of the line graph and its chromatic number

What I know for sure is that for any graph G, $\Delta(G) \leq \chi(L(G))$. My confusion is the following: When G is k-regular, $\Delta(G) = k$, and I need to show this is equal to $\chi(L(G))$. I thought about proving it with some inequality, but the only things I know to be true are that $\chi(L(G)) \leq \Delta(L(G)) = 2k - 2$ 2k-2 comes from the fact that the degree of the vertex in L(G) of edge e = (u, v) is $deg(u) + deg(v) - 2$.

Comment: What is $\chi(L(G))$?  Apparently, it's not the chromatic number.

Comment: chromatic number line graph

Comment: Thanks for clarifiying.  I thought $L(G)$ was the Laplacian, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\chi(L(G)) = \chi'(G)$, the chromatic index (or edge chromatic number) of $G$. Now since $G$ is bipartite, the chromatic index of $G$ is equal to $\Delta(G)$. See this previous question:

[Edge-coloring of bipartite graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165682/edge-coloring-of-bipartite-graphs)

But since $G$ is $k$-regular, each edge in $G$ is adjacent with $2k-2$ other edges, and $\Delta(L(G)) = 2\Delta(G)-2$. So we have:

$$\chi(L(G)) = \chi'(G) = \Delta(G) = \frac{\Delta(L(G))}{2}+1$$

Comment: I realized I had an error. Each edge is adjacent with 2k-2 other edges, not 2k-1.