# Is it true that if a graph is bipartite iff it is class 1 (edge-coloring)?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, bipartite-graphs

A graph is class 1 if its edge set can be colored with $\Delta(G)$ colors, where $\Delta(G)$ is the maximum degree over all vertices in G. A graph is class 2 if we need  $\Delta(G)+1$ colors to color the edge set. I think that if a graph is bipartite then we can color its edges with $\Delta(G)$ colors, while when it is not bipartite this cannot be done.

Is there any counterexample for this? Or is it true?

Comment: This question would be greatly improved by defining “class 1” and $\Delta(G)$

Comment: @StellaBiderman done

Comment: Do you use the definition of coloring where a graph is $m$-colorable if there is a way to assign $m$ colors legally, or do you also require that $m$ be minimal. That’s is, would you say that $C_6$ is both $2$ colorable and  $6$ colorable, or just $2$ colorable?

Comment: @StellaBiderman no I want the least $m$. So $C_6$ would be 2-colorable.

Comment: Take the complete 4 graph. Remove an edge. This has maximum degree 3, it is 3 colorable, but is not bipartite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a theorem of König that all bipartite graphs $G$ are $\Delta(G)$-edge-colorable. See this math stackexchange thread [Edge-coloring of bipartite graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/165682).

It is not true that all $\Delta(G)$-edge-colorable graphs are bipartite. Take $K_4$, which is not bipartite but is $3$-edge-colorable.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I could not find a counterexample :)